# spring cucumber Selenium fluent wait gives me driver=null

Tags: java, spring, selenium, cucumber, fluentwait

*I am trying to use fluent wait*

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
public class UserCreationPageImpl extends BaseBinariosPage implements UserCreationPage {
     Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

but when I debug I got  **drive=null**

here is where I am instanciate the driver

```
@Page
public abstract class BaseBinariosPage {
    @Autowired
    protected WebDriver driver;
    @Autowired
    private QAStarterConfigProperties qaStarterConfigProperties;

    public BaseBinariosPage() {
    }

    @Init
    public void init() {
        this.driver.get(this.qaStarterConfigProperties.getAppUrl() + this.getPageEndPoint());
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }

    protected abstract String getPageEndPoint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable it will be assigned null value by default. There is no constructor in your BaseBinariosPage that creates a driver object, how do you expect it to have a driver object.

Add something like:

```
public BaseBinariosPage() {
  driver = new ChromeDriver()
}
```